# PhantomJSDriver found Element but is still undefined

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm having a weird issue with PhantomJSDriver and Java,
I'm trying to click on a link like this :

```
WebElement loginButton =  wait.until(
                ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@ui-sref='login']"))
                );
        LOG.debug("Login Button Found :  ["+loginButton.getAttribute("href")+"]" );
        loginButton.click();
```

With Crome Driver I'm not having any issue, but with phantomsJS (2.0.0 (or 1.9.7/1.9.8) and GhostDriver 1.2.0 I'm having this kind of error :

```
[DEBUG - 2015-05-04T09:46:03.610Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) Search Start Time: 1430732763610
[DEBUG - 2015-05-04T09:46:03.612Z] WebElementLocator - _find.locator - {"using":"xpath","value":"//a[@ui-sref='login']"}
[DEBUG - 2015-05-04T09:46:03.624Z] WebElementLocator - _locateElement.locator - {"using":"xpath","value":"//a[@ui-sref='login']"}
[DEBUG - 2015-05-04T09:46:03.624Z] WebElementLocator - _locateElement.findElementResult - {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":":wdc:1430732763623"}}
[DEBUG - 2015-05-04T09:46:03.624Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand.elements - {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":":wdc:1430732763623"}}
[DEBUG - 2015-05-04T09:46:03.624Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand.rootElement - BODY
[DEBUG - 2015-05-04T09:46:03.625Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) Found. Search Stop Time: 1430732768610
```

And the error message :

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: {"errorMessage":"undefined is not an object (evaluating '(y(a)?y(a).parentWindow||y(a).defaultView:window).getComputedStyle(a,null).MozTransform.match')","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, image/png","Cache-Control":"no-cache","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Host":"localhost:7356"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"GET","url":"/displayed","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"displayed","directory":"/","path":"/displayed","relative":"/displayed","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/displayed","queryKey":{},"chunks":["displayed"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/5f287dd0-f242-11e4-9753-1726c362b9fc/element/%3Awdc%3A1430732763623/displayed"}}
Command duration or timeout: 229 milliseconds
```

I've added explicit wait before etc, but it does nothing ...
The weird part if that if I tried this code instead :

```
d.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@ui-sref='login']"));
LOG.debug("Login Button Found : ["+loginButton.getAttribute("href")+"]" );
loginButton.click();
```

I can access the href attribute !
but the click() method fail

[edit] 
The First PhanstomJS configuration looked like this :

```
// Change "User-Agent" via page-object capabilities
sCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_SETTINGS_PREFIX + "userAgent", "My User Agent - Chrome");
//  Disable "web-security", enable all possible "ssl-protocols" and "ignore-ssl-errors" for PhantomJSDriver
sCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, new String[] {
                "--web-security=false",
                "--ssl-protocol=any",
                "--ignore-ssl-errors=true",
                "--webdriver-loglevel=DEBUG"
            });


 // Fetch configuration parameters
 // "phantomjs_exec_path"
 if (sConfig.getProperty("phantomjs_exec_path") != null) {
     sCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, sConfig.getProperty("phantomjs_exec_path"));
} else {
    throw new IOException(String.format("Property '%s' not set!", PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY));
     }
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: This same error resolved in this question, see if it helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25592316/phantom-js-fails-50-of-the-time. Please add the part of the code where you are setting the phantomjs options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the below config for PhantomJS:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities;
capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();       
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "drivers/phantomjs.exe");
capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_SETTINGS_PREFIX,"Y");
capabilities.setCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20121026 Firefox/16.0");

//intialize driver and set capabilties

driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
```

Also, try finding the element this way:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byExpression));
```

Comment: Thanks !    That was really the user agent, my pseudo user agent _"My User Agent - Chrome"_ was Crap....

Comment: I don't have a PhantomJSDriver constructor that takes a DesiredCapabilities object :/